# ElasticSearch Truncate Index TypeError

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am using mongoosastic npm module. While truncating index I am getting

```
TypeError: Unable to build a path with those params. Supply at least index
```

The code I'm using

For Truncate :

```
var tagModelJS = require('../DaoModel/TagModel.js');
var TagModel = tagModelJS.getTagModel();

TagModel.esTruncate(function (err) {

    if (err) {

        console.log("ERROR : while removing data from elastic search.")
        throw err;
    }

});
```

TagModel :

```
var TAGS;
module.exports = {
    createSchemaAndGetModel : function (mongoose, mongoosastic, Schema) {
        //create schema
        var tagSchema = new Schema({
                tagDetail : String,
                userIds : [], //list of user ids
                tagName : {
                    type : [String],
                    es_indexed : true
                } // field level
            });
        tagSchema.plugin(mongoosastic)
        //create model
        TAGS = mongoose.model('TAGS', tagSchema);

        console.log("Tag model ready....");
       },

        getTagModel : function () {
            return TAGS;
        }
       };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.